# Inter Process Communication to share updates to data in Java

Tags: java, ipc, data-synchronization

I'm creating a token ring with sensors. I have client processes defined in `SensorClient` class. These client objects receive information about the list of other clients from a server process, the `createSensor` class.

The problem is that I would like clients to update the information they have when it changes on the server.

The server class:

```
    public class createSensor {

                private static createSensor instance = null;
                private ArrayList<Sensor> sensor = new ArrayList<>();
               public int position, prevPosition, nextPosition, prevPort, nextPort;

                    private createSensor() {
                    } 
 public synchronized ArrayList insertSensor(String type, String identificator, int port, String id, String gatwayAddr, long timestamp) throws IOException {

            sensor.add(new Sensor(type, identificator, port, id, gatwayAddr, timestamp));
            return new ArrayList<>(sensor); // 
        }
    }
    public synchronized boolean hasMeasurements() {
        while (InnerBuffer.getInstance().emptyInnerBuffer())
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    public synchronized void setPrevNextWhenDelete(int position,ArrayList<Sensor> sensorList) throws IOException {
//code

    }

    public synchronized ArrayList<Sensor> getSensorList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(sensor);
    }

    public synchronized int size() {
        return sensor.size();
    }

    public synchronized String returnRecentMeasurement (String id){
        String recentMeasurement=null;
        for (Sensor sensori : sensor) {
            if (sensori.getIdentificator().equalsIgnoreCase(id))
               recentMeasurement= InnerBuffer.getInstance().returnRecentMeasurements(id);
            else
                recentMeasurement = null;}
        return recentMeasurement;
    }
                public synchronized void  setPrevNextWhenAdd() throws IOException {  //some other code where int position, prevPosition, nextPosition, prevPort, nextPort get their values.


              }}
```

The client class:

```
public class SensorClient {
                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    //Starting a new sensor
         Sensor sensor = new Sensor(type,identificator,portnumber,ipnumber,gatewayAddr,timestamp);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String message = gson.toJson(sensor);
            Client c = Client.create();
            WebResource r = c.resource("http://localhost:9999/gateway/");
            ClientResponse response = r.path("sensors/add").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, message);
            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                repeat = false;
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Sensor>>(){}.getType();
                ArrayList<Sensor> sensorList = gson.fromJson(response.getEntity(String.class), collectionType);
                System.out.println("Starting the sensor ...");
                System.out.println("Push exit when you want to delete the sensor!");
                int position = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i< sensorList.size();i++){
                  if(sensorList.get(i).getIdentificator().equalsIgnoreCase(sensor.getIdentificator()) )
                        position = i;
                }

                sensors.Sensor.simulation(type, identificator);// special thread for sensors simulations
                 createSensor.getInstance().setPrevNextWhenAdd(position,sensorList);
                serverSocket serverSocket = new serverSocket(portnumber,sensorList,position,sensorList.get(position).getNext());
                serverSocket.start();

                StopSensor stopSensor = new StopSensor(identificator,portnumber,position,sensorList);
                stopSensor.start();

                   oneSensor s = new oneSensor(portnumber,sensorList);
                    s.start();
              } else {
                repeat = true;
                count +=1;
                System.out.println("Error. Wrong data! ");
            }
          }
        while (repeat );
    }
}
                        }
```

The serverSocket thread

```
public class serverSocket extends Thread {
    public int port,nextPort;
    ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList;
    public static int position;
    public serverSocket(int port, ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList,int position,int nextPort) {
        this.port = port;
        this.nextPort=nextPort;
        this.sensorList= sensorList;
        this.position=position;}
    public void run() {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
            Socket connectionSocket;
            try {
                welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                while (true) {
                    connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

                    receivedMessages thread = new receivedMessages(connectionSocket,sensorList,position,nextPort);
                    thread.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Error!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
}
```

The receivedMessages thread

```
public class receivedMessages extends Thread {

        private BufferedReader inFromClient;
        private Socket connectionSocket;
    ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList;
    int position,nextPort;
        public receivedMessages(Socket socket, ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList,int position,int nextPort){
            connectionSocket = socket;
            this.sensorList=sensorList;
            this.position=position;
            this.nextPort=nextPort;
           try {
                inFromClient = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
               } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
            @Override
        public void run() {
                //  while(true) {
                try {

                    String message = (inFromClient.readLine().toString());

                    System.out.println(message);
                    if (message.startsWith("Next") || message.startsWith("Previous")) {
                        System.out.println(message);
                    } else if (message.startsWith("The")) {

                        System.out.println(message);                        createSensor.getInstance().setPrevNextWhenDelete(position, sensorList);
                    } else  {// i receive the message that the list has changed
                    System.out.println(message);
                    sensorList = createSensor.getInstance().getSensorList();
                    System.out.println("Updated " + sensorList);}
```

Comment: Read about observer pattern

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew thanks for answering. i edited the post but don't know if more clear now

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew edited again :D the idea is that when i start a new sensor i want the other existing sensors to get the new sensorList for example, u know, not the old one they got when they were started.

Comment: okay, thanks again

Comment: yea u got it right. I explained on the comments what i can't do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Listening for changes

There are 2 possibilities for your client processes to be informed when data is modified:

- your client objects could regularly check whether list has been modified:

  - by asking for the current version of the list
  - or by asking for a timestamp of the list's modification (your server class, `createSensor`, would then have to keep a record of that)
- your client objects could open a port to listen to notifications, and your server class could notify them of a change, pushing the new list to them when the list is modified.

#### Sharing updates between the listener thread and the worker thread

In both cases, on your clients side, you will have one thread doing the work, and another thread listening for changes. That second thread will reconstruct a new list each time. In order to share it with the worker thread, here is what you can do :

- your listener thread will keep a reference to the `sensorList` that it was previously passed by the worker thread when created
- when reconstructing a new list, your listener thread will store that new list in another reference, `newList`
- your listener list can then modify the "old" list so that it matches the new list, by using `oldList.clear()` then `oldList.addAll(newList)`.

This would work, since even though the worker thread might have its own reference to the list, both references point to the same object, so it would see the changes.

#### Code for starting listener thread

For example, if your worker thread is the main thread, and it is creating the listener thread, your code could be like this, inside the worker thread code :

```
class Listener implements Runnable {

   List<Sensor> sensorList;
   Listener(List<Sensor> list ){
      sensorList = list;
   }

   public void run(){
      // code to listen to changes on the server
      // When server sends new information, thread can update the list directly:
      // sensorList.clear();
      // sensorList.addAll(newList);
   }
}

Listener l = new Listener(sensorList);
Thread listenerThread = new Thread(l);
listenerThread.start();
```

You can read about threads and how they share memory in the [Java Tutorials on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Be careful with synchronization though : when you update the old list, you should make sure other thread is not iterating over it. You should probably use `Collections.synchronizedList(sensorList)` to make sure there are no thread interferences.

Comment: well yea all sensors are processes apart. The idea of listening for changes on the list sounds great to me but then how can i change the value of that sensorList i saved when i started the sensor? I mean i will get the updated list inside the server (where i listen for changes notifications)? so i have one sensorList which has the old value and inside the new thread (listening socket) i will have the updated one. how to = their values ? so that anytime i use sensorList it has the updated list?

Comment: wow it sound a bit complicated :O don't know if i can make it :/ ps: im really new in java, some months working with it. Can you please give me some kind of code i can count on?

Comment: not really clear yet. what i don't get is the part of modifying the old list. i mean on the code above on the SensorClient class i have that sensorList which i want to be always updated when changes are done. i understood that i will save the new updated list on a variable inside the listening thread but still not getting how to pass this value to my variable sensorList on the SensorClient class O.o sorry ps: how does the listening thread to get the old list value and then to make changes on it?

Comment: no problem. you don't need to pass a value. Your listener thread, which will still have the reference to the `oldList` object, can modify it directly. Your worker thread will see these changes, because even though it has a different reference to the list, that reference points to the same object.

Comment: well i assume that in this case what im not getting is how to make this listener thread to have the reference on the old list? never done before :/ is it gonna be something like : serverSocket serverSocket = new serverSocket(portnumber,sensorList);
                serverSocket.start(); when sensorList is the old list?

Comment: it has more sense now. Thank u again :) i will try it now, hope u r still online to let u know what happens :D

Comment: in the class i have i already have a multithreaded server socket which listens for changes but actually what kind of code can i add inside the run of the code u wrote? i mean the code to listen to changes on the server. Or is there any way to connect it with that server socket i already have..?

Comment: Yes absolutely. What you call a server socket is a thread that connects to the server. If you can modify the code for that, you can pass it the reference to the list, as in my example. If you cannot, then you can add the code to connect to the server in the `run` method in the code i wrote

Comment: OMG and how can i do that? :O PS :sorry if im disturbing just that i find it difficult to do it myself and i have a lot to learn on how java works. and i edited the code to show what my serverSocket thread does

Comment: isnt that what im doing when i do:                                                                   serverSocket serverSocket = new serverSocket(portnumber,sensorList,position,sensorList.get(position).getNext()); serverSocket.start();                                                               public serverSocket(int port, ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList,int position,int nextPort) and  public receivedMessages(Socket socket, ArrayList<gateway.Sensor> sensorList,int position,int nextPort)?but then what should i insert on the // code to listen to changes on the server of the code u wrote?

Comment: im still trying to make it work o.O. And sure I should have marked it before. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You know, inter process communication and multithreading is one of the most complex aspects of programming, and of java. You are not starting with the easiest part :)

Comment: well actually i'have worked a lot and now im loosing a lot of time for this problem :/ can i ask u one more question im not really sure about? so the idea is that when i update the value of the old list inside of that thread, it guarantees me that immediately the value of the old list gets updated with the new one? so the sensor continues with the updated list? Thaaaank u :)

Comment: yes it will be immediate. But that is also one risk : if the worker thread is iterating on the list while the listener thread modifies it, you have a risk of a crash, for example if the worker thread is calling `list.get(15)` when the list is no longer 15 elements long. In order to avoid these problems, you can either prevent force the listener to wait until the worker has finished iterating, by using `synchronized`. or you can make the worker check for a flag, or for an interrupt, before attempting to read from the array, to check whether it might have been modified

Comment: the topic of synchronization is not simple, if you want to learn more you can follow the tutorial i pointed to in my answer